# Python dictionary for and if loop

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, for-loop, count

I'm very new to python. This question might be very simple.
I have two lists as below;

```
Mobile=  ('M1','M1','M1','M1','M1','M1','M1','M2','M2','M2','M2','M2','M2','M2')
Test=('call','call','sms','sms','mms','call','call','mms','mms','sms','sms','voltecall','voltecall','voltecall')
```

I want to write a loop to count how many times each Test item is done for each value in Mobile. For example I want the code to tell me 'M1' had Four 'call' scenarios, Two 'sms' and one 'mms'. 
I thought I could do this in dictionary so I created a tot variable to use as a key in dictionary and created the dictionary (as below) but i'm not sure how to use for and if statements to do what I want. The code I wrote below is not giving the correct answer. It just returns zero.

```
Mobile=  ('M1','M1','M1','M1','M1','M1','M1','M2','M2','M2','M2','M2','M2','M2')
Test=('call','call','sms','sms','mms','call','call','mms','mms','sms','sms','voltecall','voltecall','voltecall')
tot=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)

a_dict=dict(zip(tot,zip(Mobile,Test)))

for k, v in a_dict.iteritems():
    if (k==Mobile[1] and v==Test[1]):
        countM1Test1+=1
```

Comment: First why do you thik you need that tot variable?, is that usefull or necessary? Second, you can use the mobile list as keys in a dictionary, and as value the correspondance in the test variable, and then use that information to do the counts

Comment: Could you provide an example of the result you'd like to see?

Comment: When I tried zip(Mobile,Test) the dictionary that was created only had two items ('M1','call') and ('M2','voltecall'). I thought maybe dictionary requires a unique key variable, which is why i created the tot variable. What I would like to see is something like this; ('M1','call',4),('M1','sms',2),('M1','mms',1) and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultdict` with `Counter` as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
​
count = defaultdict(Counter)
for m, t in zip(Mobile, Test):
    count[m].update({t: 1})

count
# defaultdict(collections.Counter,
#             {'M1': Counter({'call': 4, 'mms': 1, 'sms': 2}),
#              'M2': Counter({'mms': 2, 'sms': 2, 'voltecall': 3})})
```

---

If you want a list of tuples, you can easily extract the tuple from the dictionary `count` above with a list comprehension:

```
[(k, a, c) for k, v in count.items() for a, c in v.items()]

# [('M1', 'mms', 1),
#  ('M1', 'sms', 2),
#  ('M1', 'call', 4),
#  ('M2', 'mms', 2),
#  ('M2', 'sms', 2),
#  ('M2', 'voltecall', 3)]
```

---

*Update*:

If you have three lists, you can make a nested *defaultdict*:

```
Mobile=  ('M1','M1','M1','M1','M1','M1','M1','M2','M2','M2','M2','M2','M2','M2')
Test=('call','call','sms','sms','mms','call','call','mms','mms','sms','sms','voltecall','voltecall','voltecall')
Response = ('error', 'success', 'skip', 'error', 'success', 'skip', 'error', 'success', 'skip', 'error', 'success', 'skip', 'error', 'success')

from collections import defaultdict, Counter

count = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(Counter))
for m, t, r in zip(Mobile, Test, Response):
    count[m][t].update({r: 1})
```

*Note*: If you have even more, I suggest you take a look at `pandas` library, it makes this type of grouped operation kind of more straight forward.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is it possible to print count one by one. when I tried to find the type of count I get a response collections.defaultdict. I tried to print count[1] but I got an error message.

Comment: `count` is a dictionary, to access the elements, you need to provide the key: `count['M1']` or `count['M2']` for instance.

Comment: A followup question, what happens if I have more than two lists to combine in a dictionary. For example I have one more list that indicates which items in Tests were 'success' or 'error' or 'skip'. How do I create a new dictionary and count as you have indicated with three lists?

Comment: Then make a `count` a nested *defaultdict*. Theoretically, you can nest as many levels as you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
pairs = zip(*(Mobile, Test))
c = Counter(pairs)
print c.items()
```

output:

[(('M1', 'sms'), 2), (('M2', 'voltecall'), 3), (('M1', 'call'), 4), (('M2', 'mms'), 2), (('M2', 'sms'), 2), (('M1', 'mms'), 1)]